# Handling multiple commands as transaction

Tags: database, payment

Im currently developing payment system which performs payment and writes that item is bought in cloud hosted database, Azure.

How it works currently is:

1. Transaction with 3rd party payment system
2. If success, new subscription row in database is added for the user
3. Transaction history and other relevant stuff is written into database

However, in an unlikely event that:

1. Transaction is success(http call to payment gateway returns success)
2. For some reason, insert in database fails

I will end up with the user having paid for an item without the actual subscription for the item.(since the row wont be in our database)

These two calls are not database related (one is, another one is simple async http request) so I cannot treat them as transaction( since I cant really rollback ).

So my question is for more experienced how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer, I've implemented this using Compensating Transaction pattern.

Works as expected